# How can I count the total number of built-in functions in PHP?

Tags: php

How can I count the total number of built-in functions in PHP, latest version?

Comment: Define "built-in". Do you mean in the core engine, or also in the common extensions? If so, what extensions?

Comment: this is like a game-show question where you have to guess what something costs.

Comment: that would be a cool game show. I take "Multi-threaded Fun" for 200.

Comment: I'd be more interested in the total number of accepted questions by coderex

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Count them here](http://php.net/manual/en/indexes.functions.php):

> #### PHP Function List
>
> Here is a list of all the documented PHP functions. Click on any one of them to jump to that page in the manual...

Comment: +1 Ahh yes, the Rainman approach. Functions .. toothpicks, cards, what's the difference? :)

Comment: This link no longer works

Answer (score 41):

You could use a core function to count the number of functions available in the core and *installed* extensions:

```
$funcs = get_defined_functions();
echo count($funcs['internal']);
```

Comment: +1 This is my favourite and completely version-independent.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

[PHP site shows a total of 5368 functions.](http://php.net/quickref.php)

Comment: I get 5701 just like Robin - you must be missing a few! ;)

Comment: I swear, i counted like three times.

Answer (score 1):

There are `5845` listed function [here at PHP website](http://php.net/quickref.php)

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/quickref.php

I selected all the functions listed on that page and pasted into a text editor.. i got 5011 lines which means that there are 5011 functions, if i am not wrong.

Comment: Question is closed, what's the point on answering?

Comment: The link is dead, and this answer has been provided before.